# Am I abusing std::optional

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

### How `std::optional` fits in my code?

My code contains MANY functions that looks roughly like:

```
bool GetName(_Out_ string& strRes)
{
   // try to get/calculate the value
   // value may also be empty
   // return true on success, false otherwise.
}
```

Now that I have found out [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), I simply code:

```
std::optional<std::string> GetName()
```

### Why or when not to use `std::optional`?

1. I understand that using `std::optional` comes with a performance price and for the sake of argument, let's assume I'm willing to pay it.
2. I also understand that coding something like:
   `std::optional<int> iVal = 9;` is pointless.

### Am I overly charmed by `std::optional`?

I find `std::optional` so natural that it lead me to a conclusion that, **by default**, many of my native types, `bool`, `int`, `string`, should be declared as `std::optional`.

So, instead of following the premise of:

> Use `std::optional` **only** when absolutely needed

I'm leaning towards:

> Use `std::optional` always **unless** you are sure it isn't needed now or
>   in the future.

### Question 1

Is the following rule valid:

use `std::optional` when:

1. a value is calculated on run time
2. calculation may fail
3. you want to know if calculation failed

### Question 2

If using `std::optional` becomes abundant, am I risking code readability issues?

---

### Update

Answers and comments steered the discussion a bit away from my initial concern which is an attempt to define a rule of thumb for when to use `std::optional`.

I will address some of the common feedback I got:

> Your are coding C-style error checking functions.
>
> use exceptions when the calculation fails.

It is perhaps my fault for providing a not-so-good example of my motivation. `GetName()` is just a taste of my common use case.
Instead of focusing on how errors are reflected (if any), I wanted to focus on **is name a good candidate for optional?**

I didn't state that if `GetName` returns false it implies some sort of error in my flow. When `GetName` return false, I could either generate a random name or just ignore the current iteration. Regardless of how the callers reacts to the return value, `name` is `optional` in a sense that it `may not be present`.

I can provide a better example:

```
void GetValuesFromDB(vector<string> vecKeys, map<string,string> mapKeyValue);
```

in this function I'm "forced" to provide two containers since I want to distinguish between:

1. key was found in DB and it is empty. this key will be in `mapKeyValue`
2. key was not found in DB. . this key will NOT be in `mapKeyValue`

But with `optional` I could go:

```
void GetValuesFromDB(map<string,std::optional<string> > mapKeyValue);
```

---

I believe that we're taking the word `optional` too literally.

I really support the notion that one may use `std::optional` [If you want to represent a nullable type nicely. Rather than using unique values (like -1, nullptr, NO_VALUE or something)](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/05/using-optional.html)

The c++ standard committee could have easily decided to name `std::optional`, `std::nullable`.

Comment: Why not use exceptions when the calculation fails?

Comment: Exceptions should never be used when a result is *expected*.

Comment: IMHO, a rule of thumb for using optional is - "If one would use pointer as return value and then test it for null then the `optional` is you friend"

Comment: If you really have a lot of functions where true means success and false means failure, but there is no error reporting involved, that might be a sign something is wrong: there could be different reasons for failure, in which case you'd normally also want to know *why* the calculation failed, i.e. an error code or error message. In which case std::optional alone won't cut it.

Comment: @stijn The functions that calc/fetch values, all register errors in one way or the other. The callers of those functions simply test the returned value to check if the can continue with their flow. My main motivation to use `std::optional` is to make code simpler, shorter and more readable. why work with two variables when you can work with one? in my example, `GetName()` is simpler to declare and simpler to be used.

Comment: Having many C++ functions with C-style error checking looks like a code smell. If those functions return false upon success to indicate that no value has been retrieved (even though no error occurred) then `std::optional` may be a reasonable choice. The only drawback would be that upon success you will be always creating a new object rather than reusing existing object passed as argument. This may result in significant performance penalty.

Comment: @VTT given those two arguments - which way would you go?

Comment: Since `std::string` is a strong candidate to be reused (just like any other container) i'd go without `std::optional`. Also note that `optional` may be also not helpful id storage of that `string` have to be used inside of that function even if it fail at the end.

Comment: Another option is somethink like  `std::variant<RetType, ErrorType>` if you want to know the reason of error.

Comment: For me; "My code contains MANY functions that looks roughly like:" is a warning sign that you're doing error handling wrong.  Returning things in a reference certainly has its uses; but - for example - can getName really fail; and if it can, should it have failed earlier?

Comment: This now reads as 4 questions and a complaint that you didn't get the answer you wanted.

Comment: _"I didn't state that if GetName returns false it implies some sort of error in my flow. When GetName return false, I could either generate a random name or just ignore the current iteration."_ So, then, it _is_ an error, and you have an idea of the appropriate way to recover from that error.

Comment: I myself am overly charmed by the proposed `std::expected<T, E>`: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0323r9.html

Answer (score 7):

> Am I abusing std::optional

Maybe.

The intended semantics of `std::optional` are to indicate that something is *optional*. That is, that if the thing is *not* present, that is OK and not an error.

If your method fails, it returns an empty optional to indicate failure. But whether this **failure** is an also an **error** depends on the semantics expected by the calling code, which you haven't shown or described: what do you do if the optional result is empty?

For example,

```
auto name = GetName();
if (!name) { diediedie(FATAL_ERROR); }
```

suggests that the name isn't really optional. If you cannot (as you say) use exceptions here, the `variant<string, error>` approach seems clearer, and also allows your failing function to communicate the failure reason that would otherwise go in an exception.

Conversely

```
auto name = GetName();
if (name) {
  cout << "User is called " << *name << '\n';
} else {
  cout << "User is anonymous\n";
}
```

seems reasonable, because failure to fetch the name is *not* an error.

---

> ### Why ... *not* to use `std::optional`?

When you don't wish to communicate that something is optional.

Obviously you *can* abuse it, like anything else, but it's likely to be confusing, misleading, unexpected and otherwise bad practise.

> ### Am I overly charmed ... ?

Maybe. If your error handling contaminates all your code, you should probably consider failing earlier, rather than stumbling on with logic that can never succeed.

If you genuinely have lots of variables that may legally be missing - in terms of your program logic - then you're probably using it correctly.

> ### Question 1

Again, it depends on what failure means in the context of your program.

> ### Question 2

Yes, your code will be an unreadable mess if *everything* is optional, partly because of the visual noise, but mostly because you can never be sure which variables even exist at a given point in your logic.

---

Your `GetValuesFromDB` edit is *probably* fine to use optional *if* your database is relatively unstructured and has no constraints. You can't depend on any particular column being populated, everything is optional, you need to manually check for the presence of every field. They're genuinely optional.

If your DB is highly structured, it may *not* be appropriate to use optional for, say, the primary key. You *cannot* have a row *without* a primary key, so making it optional seems a bit weird. Maybe it's just not worth having a separate interface for the few columns that are mandatory, though.

> I believe that we're taking the word optional too literally.

I genuinely can't tell if you even read my answer - your comment suggests you didn't understand it, at least.

Let's say we call it nullable instead. I would *still* suggest that returning `nullable<T>` for something that may legitimately not exist is fine, but returning the same type for something whose absence indicates an error, is wrong.

**You** have to decide what constitutes an error for your code. We can't do it for you, especially with the information provided. So should you use optional for everything? Maybe. Which is what I said. Decide on the semantics and preconditions of your own code, and you'll know which things are optional, which things are mandatory and whose absence should be handled as an error instead of a regular code path.

Comment: _what do you do if the optional result is empty?_ why does it matter how callers reacts to the empty `optional`? what if you have many callers and each reacts in it's own way - why would that effect the way I declare  `GetName`? `GetName` should be implement is such way that caller can know if name is valid and not empty, name is valid and empty or name could not be fetched.

Comment: As I said: what matters is whether emptiness is an error or not. You didn't provide that context, so I showed both possibilities, and described why one was a better fit for `std::optional` than the other. Your code should express intent - if your entity can legally not have a name, optional may be fine. If not having a name is a runtime error, optional is probably misleading.

Comment: The counter-example where "anonymous" people are normal/expected is convincing.

Answer (score 2):

`std::optional` is a class, that represents "optional" value. If you have a case, where you might produce a value or you might not, then optional is a way to go. Performance price is negligible (the additional condition, if the value is here might actually slow things down, but since value is optional, you will always somewhere have to check, if value is present anyway), the real price is memory:

```
printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(std::string));
printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(std::optional<std::string>));
```

prints:

```
32
40
```

on clang 64 bit.

So if you do in - let's say a structure:

```
struct A {
    std::optional<std::string> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
};

struct B {
    std::string a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
    unsigned char has_a : 1,
        has_b : 1,
        has_c : 1,
        has_d : 1,
        has_e : 1,
        has_f : 1,
        has_g : 1,
        has_h : 1;
};
```

then you will get sizeofs:

```
A - 320
B - 264
```

which might actually hurt. But usually don't.

So are you abusing optional? If you use optional to signal an error, then probably slightly yes, depending on error's context. But it always depends. If it's more important for code clarity to signal, that function didn't produce value instead of **why** it didn't produce value, then sure, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to make a short answer:

At it's core a `std::optional` is just a value with a bool (ala. `std::pair<T, bool>`). Remember that a raw pointer (in most contexts) is also optional.

In general use the following rule of thumb:

1. Use exceptions for errors/failstates/exceptional cases/etc.
2. Use only optional when needed ! Unless you are a "2nd or 3rd party" library writer, don't plan to futureproof with optionals.
3. If you expect a result, don't use optional.
4. Use optional when something is actually optionally - eg. a function that could end up finding 0 or 1 results it would make sense to return an optional. A function that could find multiple should naturally gravitate towards returning a container of results.
5. Concerning strings, sometimes using an empty string is prefered (mainly due to simplicity) instead of `std::optional<std::string>` and sometimes the reverse is true.

Answer (score -4):

I'd say this is an abuse.

I'd rewrite to `std::string getName() const` (relying on the now-required RVO) and if something untoward happens (e.g. some kind of fetching error), then throw an exception (of a custom type derived from `std::exception`). Whether or not a blank name is an error is a matter for your application.

If you are not allowed to use exceptions, then rely on C style error propagation of the form

```
int getName(std::string*) const
```

as using `std::optional` makes the actual error opaque (unless you imbue an error `struct` onto the current thread).

Comment: empty name is **NOT** a sign of an error. it is a valid, workable value. any string value is valid except when the calculation/fetch failed.

Comment: Also, we don't work with exceptions and cannot technically work with exceptions. it might be wrong/sucks but this is a constraint.

Comment: @idanshmu A constraint which is not specified in your question, though.

Comment: `getName(std::string*)` doesn't make sense, you should use `getName(std::string&)`, as the function might or might not produce value, but certainly needs a place to put value into.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski: We will have to agree to disagree on that. My way is more C-idiomatic and carries the bonus of knowing a variable might be modified at the calling site.

Comment: Yes, in C, but this is C++. You require user of your function to pass std::string by pointer, which signals, that this std::string argument **to** the function is optional. You don't signal, that function might or might not fill this argument with value.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski: Round and round we go. The OP has already discarded the C++ way: return `std::string` by value, perhaps throwing an exception.

Comment: Blatantly throwing an exception is not "the C++ way". Returning an optional for something that might (validly) just not be there at all is perfectly fine. There's no reason to go "full C" in C++ when exceptions are banned. @Radosław's suggestion is still very much a good suggestion.